# INVITE request using SIP-Sorcery c#

Tags: c#, sip, unauthorized

I'm trying to use the sip sorcery example to send and receive requests and responses to my server.I use the SIPRequest.SendRequestAsync(sipRequest) but response alsways is 401 Unauthorized

```
    private SIPTransport _sipTransport;
    private SIPRequest sipRequest;
    
    public SIPTransportLayer()
            {
                // Configure the SIP transport layer.
            }
    
    public async Task<SocketError> SendInviteRequestAsync()
            {
                SIPURI uri = SIPURI.ParseSIPURI("sip:" + "6005" + "@10.100.1.29:5060");
    
                //Creat SIP Request
                sipRequest = _sipTransport.GetRequest(
                    SIPMethodsEnum.INVITE,
                    uri,
                    new SIPToHeader(
                        null,
                        new SIPURI(uri.User, uri.Host, null, uri.Scheme, SIPProtocolsEnum.udp),
                        null
                        ),
                    );
                sipRequest.Header.From = new SIPFromHeader(USERNAME, uri_From, "tag");
    
                //Send request
                return await _sipTransport.SendRequestAsync(sipRequest);
            }
```

I'm trying add Authenticate

```
private void _sipTransport_SIPTransportResponseReceived(SIPEndPoint localSIPEndPoint, SIPEndPoint remoteEndPoint, SIPResponse sipResponse)
        {
            if (sipResponse.StatusCode == 401 && sipResponse.Header.CSeqMethod == SIPMethodsEnum.INVITE)
            {
                //Resubscribe with Digist
                //SIP Header
                sipRequest.Header.CSeq++;
                sipRequest.Header.CallId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                sipRequest.Header.AuthenticationHeader = sipResponse.Header.AuthenticationHeader;
                sipRequest.Header.Expires = 120;

                //SIP Authenticate
                SIPAuthorisationDigest authDigest = sipResponse.Header.AuthenticationHeader.SIPDigest;
                authDigest.SetCredentials(USERNAME, PASSWORD, DOMAIN, SIPMethodsEnum.INVITE.ToString());
                sipRequest.Header.AuthenticationHeader = new SIPAuthenticationHeader(authDigest);
                sipRequest.Header.AuthenticationHeader.SIPDigest.Response = authDigest.Digest;

                //Send request
                _sipTransport.SendRequestAsync(sipRequest);
            }
        }
```

**Update**: I want to send SIP INVITE message to Asterisk server with SDP of Janus Gateway and receiver SDP like diagram:

[Diagram 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bfNcE.png)

[Diagram 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SkEH6.png)

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example of how to do it (note my example uses the latest version of the sipsorcery code whereas you may be using an earlier version).

But this is a very had way to deal with SIP calling. Ideally you should use the `SIPUserAgent` class it wraps up the lower level logic:

`SIPUserAgent` -> `SIPClientUserAgent` -> `UACInviteTransaction` -> `SIPRequest`/`SIPResponse`

You are attempting to use the lowest level `SIPRequest`/`SIPResponse` primitives and will have to do a lot of extra work. For example you need to send `ACK` requests, handle information (Trying/Ringing responses), deal with retransmits, handle various other error responses, detect duplicate responses etc. `SIPUserAgent` already does all this for you.

```cs
using System;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using SIPSorcery.SIP;

namespace SIPInviteAuthentication
{
    class Program
    {
        static string USERNAME = "username";
        static string PASSWORD = "password";
        static string SERVER = "some.server.com";
        static string DST = "sip:1234@some.server.com";

        static SIPTransport _sipTransport;
        static bool _authRequestSent;

        static async Task Main()
        {
            _sipTransport = new SIPTransport();
            _sipTransport.SIPTransportResponseReceived += SIPTransportResponseReceived;

            await SendInviteRequestAsync();

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static Task<SocketError> SendInviteRequestAsync()
        {
            SIPURI dstUri = SIPURI.ParseSIPURIRelaxed(DST);
            return _sipTransport.SendRequestAsync(GetInviteRequest(dstUri));
        }

        static Task SIPTransportResponseReceived(SIPEndPoint localSIPEndPoint, SIPEndPoint remoteEndPoint, SIPResponse sipResponse)
        {
            if (sipResponse.Header.CSeqMethod == SIPMethodsEnum.INVITE && sipResponse.StatusCode >= 200)
            {
                if(sipResponse.Status == SIPResponseStatusCodesEnum.Ok)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Authorisation successful.");
                }
                else if(sipResponse.Status == SIPResponseStatusCodesEnum.Unauthorised && !_authRequestSent)
                {
                    _authRequestSent = true;

                    SIPURI dstUri = SIPURI.ParseSIPURIRelaxed(DST);

                    // Resend INVITE with credentials.
                    SIPAuthorisationDigest digest = sipResponse.Header.AuthenticationHeader.SIPDigest;
                    digest.SetCredentials(USERNAME, PASSWORD, DST, SIPMethodsEnum.INVITE.ToString());

                    SIPRequest authInviteRequest = GetInviteRequest(dstUri);
                    authInviteRequest.Header.AuthenticationHeader = new SIPAuthenticationHeader(digest);
                    authInviteRequest.Header.AuthenticationHeader.SIPDigest.Response = digest.Digest;

                    return _sipTransport.SendRequestAsync(authInviteRequest);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Authorisation failed with {sipResponse.Status}.");
                }
            }

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        static SIPRequest GetInviteRequest(SIPURI dstUri) =>
             SIPRequest.GetRequest(
                SIPMethodsEnum.INVITE,
                dstUri,
                new SIPToHeader(null, dstUri, null),
                new SIPFromHeader(null, new SIPURI(USERNAME, SERVER, CallProperties.CreateNewTag()), CallProperties.CreateNewTag())
            );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but still not working. I don't want use Sip User Agent because my server just send Legacy SDP from Janus Gateway to Asterisk server